# Keep track with subversion and googlecode

Tags: svn, google-code

I have an svn repository in GoogleCode, i have subversion installed in my Ubuntu and a symfony project in a directory called sfTesting. I'm a newbie user of both GoogleCode and subversion.

How can I import, export and keep track of my symfony project ?

Thks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a new local repository with file from your Google Code project:

```
svn checkout http://sftesting.googlecode.com/svn/trunk sfTesting
```

To see which files you have changed on your computer:

```
svn status
```

To add and remove files:

```
svn add foo.txt
svn remove foo.txt
```

To commit your changes to your Google Code project:

```
svn commit -m "Modified some files." http://sftesting.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

To update your local repository with changes from your Google Code project:

```
svn update
```

Consult the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) or `man svn` for complete documentation.

Comment: Tks a lot. My fault was not to specify the project name in the checkout command.

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout (no pun intended) the google-code-specific [Subversion FAQ.](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ) Here's an older, still useful, but [Windows-centric tutorial.](https://devwatch.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/how-to-access-google-code-svn/)